# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" in Maven build

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory, permgen

I'm  getting this error while building Maven project, I increased MAVEN_OPTS but all the same, I found some similar posts but they are refering to something else. How do I fix this?

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedClassLoader.java:56)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.<init>(Annotate.java:52)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.instance(Annotate.java:36)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:215)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.instance(ClassReader.java:168)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.<init>(JavaCompiler.java:293)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.instance(JavaCompiler.java:72)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:340)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:420)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:493)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
```

I'm not as worried about how to fix as to how to fix it *in the maven ecosystem*

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions if you search SO for "PermGen space"

Comment: umm this is while deploying to tomcat I havent got so far yet so its not the same as you see I dont even use tomcat I use jboss error is during the maven build

Comment: @Paul Tomblin I agree but none of them refer to errors while building a project

Comment: But the solution is the same: increase PermGen space on the JavaVM (in this case: the one that runs maven)

Comment: @Andreas_D you mean MAVEN_OPTS? I already increased that

Comment: @Paul Tomblin can you remove your duplicate comments I want to accept Icarus answer but it will get closed before likely

Comment: @Gandalf, the arguments to the Java vm to increase permgenspace are the same whether you're doing it in Tomcat or Maven or Eclipse or whatever.

Comment: @Gandalf - this is a recommendation I found for Maven: `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: My setting is 1024 for heap space and 512 for maxpermsize .. its working like a charm

Comment: Note that if you have multiple modules it might be beneficial to tell the maven-compiler-plugin to fork.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

When you say you increased `MAVEN_OPTS`, what values did you increase? Did you increase the `MaxPermSize`, as in example:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
```

(or on Windows:)

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

You can also specify these JVM options [in each maven project separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998748/32453).

Comment: Can I set this property somehow in pom.xml? I need to make my build portable to different environments.

Comment: he knows that. not what he asked

Comment: just a note for mac/linux users, just add an export statement to your  ~/.profile (or similar file name).  For example:
    export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
...and restart your shell.  Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you really much. Your solution saved me from a lot of frustration !

Comment: In case of building the project using the command use this
-DXmx512m -DXX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: on Unix `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"`

Comment: Don't forget. In java 8 max perm size goes away.

Comment: Our integration tests consume a lot of memory, so the only way to avoid this problem was to set the following env variable:
`export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"`

Comment: MaxPermSize is deprecated in Java 8

Comment: excellent ...last 2.5 hours I was trying lot of options and your solution worked like a charm...thanks a lot :)

Comment: As a note, you don't have to always specify `Xmx`, it does get fairly generous defaults https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined :)

Answer (score 24):

If you want to make this part of your POM for a repeatable build, you can use the fork-variant of a few of the plugins (especially [compiler:compile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) and [surefire:test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
      <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
      <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Better have it in the pom so that other developers/environments won't encounter the OOME.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it changes with Java versions, so some standardisation might be still required. (For example using %JAVA_1_7_HOME% like Apache Commons is doing (since toolchain might not be ready for beeing used in those situations).

Comment: Would adding this arg cause a JVM warning/error when running build on Java 1.8?

Comment: @djangofan yes. (It is not untypical to use java-8 profiles. They can even use JAVA_1_8_HOME which would emulate a poor mens toolchain selector)

Comment: the best. works like a charm

Answer (score 16):

Increase the size of your perm space, of course.  Use the `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` option.  Set the value to something appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this exception, I solved this by using Run Configurations... panel as picture shows below.Especially, at JRE tab, the VM Arguments are the critical 
 ( **"-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=512m"** ).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This very annoying error so what I did:
Under Windows:

```
Edit system environment variables - > Edit Variables -> New
```

then fill

```
MAVEN_OPTS
-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

[image]

Then restart the console and run the maven build again. No more Maven space/perm size problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution of git bash command when you try to build war using git mvn clean install for
    “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space” in Maven build error come

```
use below command first 

$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xss32m"

then use your mvn command to clean install /build war file

$ mvn clean install

NOTE: you don't need -XX:MaxPermSize argument in MAVEN_OPTS when your are using jdk1.8
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=XXXm; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We face this error when permanent generation heap is full and some of us we use command prompt to build our maven project in windows. since we need to increase heap size, we could set our environment variable @ControlPanel/System and Security/System and there you click on  ***Change setting*** and select Advanced and set Environment variable as below

- Variable-name : MAVEN_OPTS
- Variable-value : -XX:MaxPermSize=128m