# Maven enunciate plugin java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, maven-3

Here is the maven code snippet

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${enunciate.version}</version>
<configuration>
<configFile>enunciate-config.xml</configFile>
<buildDir>${project.build.directory}</buildDir>
<javacArguments>
<source>1.7</source>
<target>1.7</target>
</javacArguments>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>docs</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

On running getting exception

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Env.dup(Env.java:95)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.methodEnv(MemberEnter.java:610)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitMethodDef(MemberEnter.java:570)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:669)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:401)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:413)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.finishClass(MemberEnter.java:423)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.finish(MemberEnter.java:1062)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:1022)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:421)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:821)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:491)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.AptJavaCompiler.compile(AptJavaCompiler.java:262)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1127)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:989)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:113)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:103)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.invokeApt(Enunciate.java:812)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doGenerate(Enunciate.java:396)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.ConfigMojo$MavenSpecificEnunciate.doGenerate(ConfigMojo.java:646)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.step(Enunciate.java:1773)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.stepTo(Enunciate.java:1805)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:96)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
```

I want to know how i can increase the xmx, xms , perm memory to overcome the issue.It happen at the time of code generation it looks like.Actually the number of java files in classpath are quite huge Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look on this question :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498738/maven-out-of-memory-build-failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498738/maven-out-of-memory-build-failure)

Comment: @Kalher Thanks. I am getting outofMemory error at the time of generating source code (from jars) which is not the compilation phase.Actually i tried          
 '<plugin>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0</version>
 <configuration>
 <fork>true</fork>
 <meminitial>1024m</meminitial>
 <maxmem>6144m</maxmem>
 <compilerArgs>
 <arg>-XX:MaxPermSize=6144m</arg>
 </compilerArgs>
 <source>1.7</source>
 <target>1.7</target>
 </configuration>  
 </plugin>'

Comment: Any suggestion please ?????