# How is Maven ignoring -Xmx set through MAVEN_OPTS in openjdk:8-jdk-alpine?

Tags: docker, maven, alpine-linux

I can't for the life of me figure out why `-Xmx` in `MAVEN_OPTS` doesn't work for Maven in `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`.

This:

```
$ docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'apk add maven && MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2g\ -Xms2g mvn --version'
```

Produces:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

I've used `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to look at `MaxHeapSize` with various settings and here's what I found:

- Apparently `-Xmx` is fixed to 512mb regardless of what's specified.  Other options such as `-Xms` and `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` work as expected:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'apk add maven && \
      MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx123m -Xms123m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal" mvn --version | egrep "(Initial|Max)HeapSize"'

      uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 130023424                           {product}
      uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 536870912                           {product}
  ```
- `apt add maven` is installing maven version `3.6.0-r0` but trying with other versions also produce the same result. For example, `3.6.1-r0` in Alpine 3.10 and `3.5.2-r0` in Alpine 3.7 produced the same result:

  ```
  $ docker run openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'sed -e s:/v3.9/:/v3.10/: /etc/apk/repositories -i && \
      apk add maven && MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2g\ -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal mvn -version | fgrep MaxHeapSize'
  ```
- I've looked for `~/.m2/settings.xml` and `./.mvn` as mentioned in https://maven.apache.org/configure.html but neither seem to exist:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'apk add maven && ls ~/.m2'
  ```
- `java` seems to support `-Xmx` fine:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'java -Xmx2g -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | fgrep MaxHeapSize'
  ```
- The problem doesn't occur if `maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine` is used instead of `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine sh -c \
      'MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2g\ -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal mvn --version | fgrep MaxHeapSize'
  ```
- Using `_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead of `MAVEN_OPTS` works as a workaround:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'apk add maven && \
      _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2g\ -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal mvn --version | fgrep MaxHeapSize'
  ```

Question is, how is `-Xmx` in `MAVEN_OPTS` being ignored for Maven in `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`?

Comment: `MAVEN_OPTS` is an environment variable for Maven and NOT for the JDK which you are using via `docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine..` If you are using the image `docker run --rm maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine` which is a Maven image where you can simply define via `-e MAVEN_OPTS="..."`  (as environment variable)... where no need is to use `sh -c  'MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2g\ -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal mvn --version..` ....

Comment: `MAVEN_OPTS` a [standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498738) of setting JVM options such as `-Xmx` [even on offical documentation](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html).  I could set it through `docker run`'s `-e` like you said or through the `VAR=value cmd` syntax of the shell but it doesn't really make a difference to `mvn` does it?  This seems moot as far as the issue is concerned but if I'm going to have a shell anyway to do `apk add maven` then why not put it in front of the command as it's shorter that way.

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand my point: MAVEN_OPTS is not a standard way setting JVM options in general it's way to set JVM options for the JVM which is used by Maven (technically it's used by `mvn` script to [configure the JVM options](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.8.1/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn)). The usage via `docker run -e MAVEN_OPTS..` will only work for the Maven image(`maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine`) but not for the `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` image and of course the behaviour changes if you use different images.

Comment: I thought the comment was pointing out something problematic with some code in the question but I couldn't tell which part.  The `docker run -e MAVEN_OPTS=...` syntax first appeared in your comment and all code in the question uses the `MAVEN_OPTS=... mvn` syntax where `MAVEN_OPTS` goes directly into the `mvn` script.

Answer (score 4):

This obscure problem is documented in this equally [hard to find bug report](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/8762).  Basically, Maven on Alpine Linux is packaged with an `/etc/mavenrc` file containing these lines:

```
M2_HOME="$m2_home"
MAVEN_OPTS="\$MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx512m"
```

The problem lies in the second line which hard codes `-Xmx` to 512m.  So yes, `-Xmx` cannot be set through `MAVEN_OPTS` on Alpine Linux's vanilla Maven as of time of writing.

To test, simply remove the file and try again:

```
$ docker run --rm openjdk:8-jdk-alpine sh -c 'apk add maven && rm /etc/mavenrc && \
    MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2g\ -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal mvn --version | fgrep MaxHeapSize'
```

`MaxHeapSize` should then be set to the desired 2g.

The bug report is three years old and probably hasn't gained more traction because there's couple of conditions that need satisfying: Using Maven on Alpine Linux and requiring more than 512m to build.

A person who stumbles on this has few options:

- Use `_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead of `MAVEN_OPTS` for setting `-Xmx`
- Remove the second line of `/etc/mavenrc`

Hopefully for them, an OOM error will come quickly and painlessly, instead of extremely slow builds due to excessive GC'ing.