# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error

Tags: maven, out-of-memory, permgen

I've read all kind of solutions for this. A [link](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html) in a comment in

[Dealing with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

is the best I've found so far. Pretty complicated to follow though.

The point is, I get this error just compiling a project with Maven.

To my knowledge there is no aplication server so far. SO what's going on?

And what can I do?

This is my error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:02.743s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 24 17:48:50 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 77M/894M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/aether-a
pi-1.13.1.jar
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/aether-c
onnector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/aether-i
mpl-1.13.1.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/aether-s
pi-1.13.1.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/aether-u
til-1.13.1.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/commons-
cli-1.2.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-ae
ther-provider-3.0.4.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-ar
tifact-3.0.4.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-co
mpat-3.0.4.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-co
re-3.0.4.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-e
mbedder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-m
odel-3.0.4.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-m
odel-builder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-p
lugin-api-3.0.4.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-r
epository-metadata-3.0.4.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-s
ettings-3.0.4.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/maven-s
ettings-builder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/plexus-
cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/plexus-
component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/plexus-
interpolation-1.14.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/plexus-
sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/plexus-
utils-2.0.6.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/sisu-gu
ava-0.9.9.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/sisu-gu
ice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/sisu-in
ject-bean-2.3.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/sisu-in
ject-plexus-2.3.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/wagon-f
ile-2.2.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/wagon-h
ttp-2.2-shaded.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-3.0.4/lib/wagon-p
rovider-api-2.2.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 10):

Please see this question:
["java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" in Maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101128/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

(or)

Please see this link:
http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2007/07/26/quicktip-how-to-increase-the-java-heap-memory-for-maven-2-on-linux/

> If you get an error OutOfMemory error while doing mvn site, because of
>   all the reports that you are generating, just increase the heap size
>   for maven2. The way to do that on linux.
>
> In your mvn.sh add this as the first line after the copyright and
>   other comments.
>
> export MAVEN_OPTS=”-Xmx512m”
>
> note than Maven 2.0.6 onwards some users have reported that the double
>   quotes give problems, hence you might want to use
>
> export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m

Comment: set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m" worked for me on Windows

Comment: On mac osx, i need to set `-XX:MaxPermSize` as well, ie. `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"`