# What does <fork>true</fork> means in pom.xml while using maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using maven 3.3.3. and I have  `<fork>true</fork>`. I ran into issues(MojoException) and fixed it by commenting out

```
 <fork>true</fork>
 <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
```

My project was using Java 1.6 and java.version in above line refers to 1.6, but my computer environment variables was 1.7 and maven 3.3.3 needs Java 1.7 . Now my issues are fixed.

But I am not able to understand 
1) what does fork mean here?
2) What does it do?
3) Having it set to true or false, what changes it?

I went through the documentation, but it is hard to follow. Thanks.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#fork

Comment: @StackFlowed How the heck does one get to that page from the Maven Compiler Plugin documentation at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html ?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer this is for the Plugin sites always the same, click on "Goals" in the menu and then select the actual goal (`compiler:compile`) you want more details.

Comment: @eckes Cool, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`true` means it will create (fork) a new JVM to run the compiler. This is a bit slower but the isolation is better.

Especially you can specify a different JVM than the one Maven is started with, and you can also specify command line parameters ([for increasing Heapsize or Metaspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101128/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-in-maven-build/27283480#27283480)) only in this case. In your case it causes problems as it seem to use the wrong JVM, you could specify the [full path with `<executable>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) or a [toolchain configuration](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).

This is one method to use a modern Maven which does not run with Java 1.6, but still use a clean compile environment for older source/target versions.

`false` means it is startign the compiler directly in the JVM you have run maven with, this makes the build less repeatable.

Comment: So in my case since my project (that is, in pom.xml java.version is set as 1.6), but maven is 3.3.3. and setting fork=true, starts a new jvm 7 and tries to execute 1.6 code in it. Am I right?

Comment: I think it starts any Java executable it finds on the PATH first if you do not use toolchain or <executable> settings.

Comment: Yes, There is a <executable> in my pom.xml as well and it refers to 1.6

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence. I was just looking for a way to get IntelliJ to build my Java 6 maven project, while using Maven 3.3.9. Gonna try that.